Magento 2 : Default Billing Country Showing on Checkout
When I load the checkout I find country name in billing address already. This is Magento 2 default code which render this in file
Module_Checkout\template\billing-address\details.html
<text args="getCountryName(currentBillingAddress().countryId)"></text><br>


How to stop showing on page load.

In the Admin area, Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > General > Country Options > Default Country, select the first item of the selection "--Please select--" . (Check the correct scope of the store to avoid overwrites)
Then clean 'Configuration' and 'Page Cache' caches (System > Tools > Cache Management).
And finally you have to clear cookies from the browser.
